# Download a multipart message using curl

Tags: curl

I have a file uploaded to a server as a multipart file. It looks like this.

```
--c3bfe99041a144af90f7834a73a4da39
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="README"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


CONTENT

--c3bfe99041a144af90f7834a73a4da39--
```

I am only interested in the CONTENT of the file. Is there way to automatically strip off those multipart header messages and download only the content using curl, the command line tool?